# Association build method creates empty nil class at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm not sure why but when I loop `@booth.chats.build` then run

With below code, I get an empty `chat` class at the last part of the iteration

```
- @booth.chats.each_with_index do |chat, index|
          = render partial: "chats/chat", locals: { chat: chat }
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: Because you created one with `@booth.chats.build`?

Comment: @MarekLipka is there a way to ensure it doesn't append with empty object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@booth.chats.build` will build an instance but it is not saved just like below

`#<Chat id: nil, name: nil, ...`

so after that when you try to execute `@booths.chats.each_with_index` it will return empty one as it is not saved

Hope I am able to clear your doubts

better you can save [`@booths.chats.save!`] it and then try that

Answer (score 0):

The "build" method makes a new Chat object and appends it the "chats" association (without saving to the database). You can still enumerate over the "chats" association without having to call "build" first.